# Preview fails in Lyx in recent versions of Linux Mint

Tags: lyx

I cannot preview documents in Lyx. For example:

[image]

Note that export works fine.

Any idea of how I can diagnose what is going on?

I am on **Linux Mint**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recent versions of Linux Mint use a new PDF viewer, called `xreader`, which Lyx does not automatically recognize.

Go to Tools -> Preferences -> File Handling -> File Formats. In the Format dropdown, select PDF (pdflatex). Then, where it says Viewer, select Custom, and type `xreader`.

[image]

Comment: Note that this should not be needed for LyX 2.3.0 thanks to this commit: https://www.lyx.org/trac/changeset/bcf8a40a/lyxgit

Comment: In Xubuntu I had to change this to atril, which was the default viewer